# Composite View widgets not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I am trying to make a composite view by extending `RelativeLayout` It consists of three widgets. An `ImageView` , a `ProgressBar` and a `TextView` . But for some reason I am unable to see the `ImageView` and `TextView`. Attaching code below. Any suggestions?

```
public class ProgressView extends RelativeLayout {

@InjectView(R.id.ivItemPic)
ImageView ivItemPic;
@InjectView(R.id.tvMessage)
TextView tvMessage;
@InjectView(R.id.pbLoading)
ProgressBar pbLoading;

int defColor = 0xff669900;

public ProgressView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context,null, 0);
}

public ProgressView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context,attrs, 0);
}

public ProgressView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context,attrs, defStyle);
}

public void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    inflate(context, R.layout.component_progress_view, this);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);

    TypedArray aTypedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ProgressView, defStyleAttr, 0);

    final int textSize = aTypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.styleable.ProgressView_pvTextSize,
            dipsToPix(R.dimen.font_medium));

    final int textColor = aTypedArray.getColor(R.styleable.ProgressView_pvTextColor,defColor);

    final Drawable imgSrc = aTypedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.ProgressView_pvImageSrc);
    ivItemPic.setImageDrawable(imgSrc);

    tvMessage.setTextSize(textSize);
    tvMessage.setTextColor(textColor);

    aTypedArray.recycle();
}

/**
 * Helper method to convert dips to pixels.
 */
private int dipsToPix(float dps) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dps,
            getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}

public void setText(String message) {
    tvMessage.setText(message);
}

public void imageVisibility(boolean visible) {
    ivItemPic.setVisibility(visible ? VISIBLE : GONE);
}

public void progressIndeterminate(boolean indeterminate) {
    pbLoading.setIndeterminate(indeterminate);
}

public void setItemImage(Drawable drawable) {
    ivItemPic.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}

public void setItemImageRes(int res) {
    ivItemPic.setImageResource(res);
}
```

The XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivItemPic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/pbLoading"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_info"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pbLoading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pbLoading"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium"
    android:textColor="@color/grey_normal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Message"/>
```

The Layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:errorview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background_color"
tools:context="com.mobility.ui.SyncFragment">

<com.mobility.customviews.SuccessView
    android:id="@+id/svSuccess"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:svText="Success"
    app:svTextColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>


<tr.xip.errorview.ErrorView
    android:id="@+id/evError"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    errorview:ev_errorSubtitle="@string/err_conn"
    errorview:ev_errorTitle="@string/oops"
    errorview:ev_showRetryButton="true"
    errorview:ev_showSubtitle="true"
    errorview:ev_showTitle="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
    errorview:ev_retryButtonTextColor="@color/error_retry"/>

<com.mobility.customviews.ProgressView
    android:id="@+id/progressView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:pvText="ZzZZ"/>
```

[image: The Output]

Comment: i am facing same issue , any luck ?